# Etymology of word фум-лента

Tags: этимология, лексикон

What is the etymology of the Russian word фум-лента (for isolating waterpipes)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an abbreviation of "Фторопластовый уплотнительный материал", nothing less nothing more. 
So it's basically means that this is a fluoroplastic.